# log4net: synchronize file writing among processes

Tags: .net, log4net

I have a console application which writes its log into a single specified log file. The program does some (long) batch elaboration, and it can happen that it's called again while this elaboration is still in progress (so two processes write the same file).
I have a RollingFileAppender, and everything works fine (i use InterProcessLock) till the rolling time, when it occurs I have an exception. I read that this is normal because log4net does not ensure "process sync" in RollingFileAppender.
How could I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is having each process write to it's own file a possibility? Trying to solve the problem of two log4net processes writing to the same log file is going to be fairly difficult.

Comment: Now we still have each process writing it's own log file, but it's quite a pain specially for log analisys. Maybe if exsisted a good smart log joiner it would be a possibility...

Comment: What about switching to a log format that is not a flat file, perhaps a SQLite database or a custom event category in the windows event log? (A custom windows event category is the solution I used for my log4net project where I had to solve the same issue as you)

Comment: Those would be fine solutions, but I must have log text file because twice a day there's another app which read log files for monitoring purpose.

Comment: We're working (internally, sorry but cannot share the code) on an approach where log4net writes to a message queue and then the queue is read by a background process and written to a file.